# How do I create an indentation in the first line of every paragraph?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Paragraph indenting not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41653/paragraph-indenting-not-working)

I'm using parameters as below.

```tex
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}
```

I'm using `\\`, `\\\\` and `\linebreak` to create new paragraphs but it not seems to work properly: only first paragraph in the section is indented.

### Working example

```
Документация программисту должна содержать описание структуры базы данных, инструкции по созданию собственных модулей и страниц, а также всех функций и переменных, используемых в системе. Первая составляющая создаётся компоновкой описанных выше разделов отчёта, относящихся к базе данных в один файл, поэтому может быть опущена.\linebreak
Описание всех функций и переменных, используемых в системе, может быть создано как очевидным (но в то же время рутинным и долгим) способом --- ручным набором документации, --- так и с помощью автоматизированных средств, наиболее распространёнными из которых являются phpDocumentor и Doxygen.\linebreak
В работе было использовано последнее, поскольку распространяется в виде исполняемого файла, а не набора скриптов, быстрее создаёт документацию из большого количества файлов, и не требует установки дополнительных библиотек.
```

Comment: Paragraphs in TeX and LaTeX are delimited by empty lines. For more detailed help please provide a working example.

Comment: Added example. Okay, when I'm writing `\\\\` I'm creating an empty line (am I?) but it doesn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paragraph indenting not working](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41653/12850).

Comment: Your example is not a complete document (that typically goes from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that could be compiled with LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks @StephanLehmke. I didn't realize that empty line means empty line itself and shouldn't be created with latex commands.

Comment: @efpies: The correct command is `\par`, but empty lines are preferable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TeX differentiates between line breaks and paragraphs. To begin a new line use `\\`, `\linbreak` or `\newline`. Then TeX makes a break but form it’s point of view you’re still in the same paragraph. To begin a new paragraph insert an empty line *in the source code* or insert `\par`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}% too much in my eyes delete this
                             % line and use the default ...

\begin{document}
    This is my first paragraph\\
    which is continued in a new line.

    After a blank line a new paragraph begins
    and is indented by TeX

    These paragraphs are indented, since they aren't
    preceeded by a headline.

    \section{Headline}
    It's recommended to not indent the first
    paragraph after a headline. If you want this
    use the \texttt{indentfirst} package.
\end{document}
```

[image: paragraphs in TeX]